# how to resolve this issue with my flutter app in Android Studio, it doesn't let me build app bundle

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color build appbundle

Building with sound null safety

Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:5.1.1.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/5.1.1/gradle-5.1.1.pom
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/5.1.1/gradle-5.1.1.jar
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/5.1.1/gradle-5.1.1.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/5.1.1/gradle-5.1.1.jar
> Required by:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75579664/13973724. try this approach.

Comment: this is what i got after following the https://stackoverflow.com/a/75579664/13973724 instruction...

Comment: It's still not working